# What's a good scripting language if I'm developing for Android?

Tags: java, javascript, android, scripting, lua

I'm writing an application in Java that I would eventually like to run on Android devices (right now it runs on desktop).  I've recently been thinking about adding a scripting language, but am not sure what to pick.

My preference is Javascript/ECMAScript since I'm already familiar with it, but I can't find a pure java port of it, which I think would make it hard to compile into an Android executable (at least I think so.  I don't know if/how Android handles JNI).

I was also thinking of Lua since a pure Java version does seem to be available under the MIT license.  I believe Minecraft uses it for scripting.

If anyone else knows of any good scripting languages I ought to consider or a clean port of Javascript, please let me know.

Comment: Android handles JNI and uses it all over the place internally. You'd just have to make sure that you can build the native part as ARM (and x86 for some devices) linux library. See https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rhino) is a pure Java implementation of JavaScript, which is [co-bundled with JDK7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/#jsengine). You can compile JavaScript to bytecode, or compile on-the-fly from JavaScript source.

Comment: Android does unfortunately not ship with a `javax.script` package even though the latest version is Java 7 at the core language level. It might work to include it manually but then again, Android does not even use standard bytecode.

Comment: True, Dalvik isn't a JVM. But as Rhino provides JavaScript-to-Java-bytecode, and Dalvik provides Java-bytecode-to-Dalvik-bytecode, you should be able to write JavaScript to run on Android. Compiling on the fly may be more of a challenge. But as kitfox was asking for a "pure Java" scripting language, Rhino jumped out.